# Import CSV (flat file) using SQL Server Management Studio in existing table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2016

May someone please let me know if there is a way to import CSV files in an existing table using SQL Server Management Studio GUI

I tried the below but this method always creates a new table and will not allow importing in an existing table:

```
*Right click the database and select Tasks -> Flat File...
Click the Next > button.
For Data Source, select Flat File Source. Then use the Browse button to select the CSV file.  Spend some time configuring the data import before clicking the Next > button.*
```

Comment: Right Click Database -> Tasks -> Import Data. Follow instructions in the wizard; ensure you select your existing table when you get to the relevant screen (which you clearly were not).

Comment: on the "select source tables and views" window  in the right hand side under destination click on the "new" table name and a down arrow should appear that will show you exg tables to select

Comment: You know Sql Server 2008 is end of life right? It no longer gets any updates... **not even critical security patches**, of which there are now several. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using this.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found a solution to import my data from a CSV file into an existing table using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do it:
**Please note the main point or step that I was missing on earlier was not doing the right-click on the existing table in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and choose "Import Data" from the context menu. This step is crucial because it initiates the data import process with the intention of importing data into the selected existing table, rather than creating a new one.**

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS): Start by launching SQL
   Server Management Studio on your computer.
2. Connect to Your Database: Connect to the SQL Server instance where
   your database and existing table are located. Enter the server name
   and your authentication credentials.
3. Locate the Existing Table: In the Object Explorer, navigate to the
   specific database that contains the table where you want to import
   data. Expand the "Tables" node to find your existing table.
4. Initiate the Import Data Wizard: Right-click on the name of the
   existing table. From the context menu that appears, select "Import
   Data..." This will open the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.
5. Choose a Data Source: In the wizard, you'll see the "Choose a Data
   Source" page. Here, select "Flat File Source" as the data source.
   Click the "Browse" button to locate and select the CSV file you want
   to import.
6. Configure Data Source Settings: Depending on your CSV file's format,
   you may need to configure settings like the delimiter used in the
   file. Ensure these settings match your CSV file.
7. Specify Destination: Proceed to the "Choose a Destination" page.
   Choose "SQL Server Native Client" as the destination, and click the
   "Next" button to continue.
8. Choose Destination Table: On the "Specify Table Copy or Query" page,
   select the destination table where you want to import data. Make
   sure the "Enable identity insert" option is unchecked unless you
   specifically need to insert identity values from the CSV file. You
   can click the "Edit Mappings" button if you need to customize column
   mappings.
9. Review and Confirm: Review the settings on the subsequent pages of
   the wizard to ensure they match your requirements.
10. Save or Run the Package: On the "Save and Run Package" page, choose
    whether to save the SSIS package for future use or run it
    immediately. Make your selection, then click "Next" and "Finish."
11. Monitor the Import Process: The wizard will now begin importing
    data from the CSV file into your selected table. You can monitor
    the progress in the wizard interface.

Completion: Once the import is completed, you should see a summary of the process, including any potential errors or warnings that may have occurred during the import.

Comment: That's shown in all tutorials.

Comment: So, you take the answer someone else provided and write it out a little and then claim it as your answer? Here the downvotes com. Stolen Valour on top of Missing Reading makes a great combo.

Comment: There's an entire section in the [SSIS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-data-sources-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16) that show how to import data step by step. There's a separate article for each one, including for [Flat text files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-flat-file-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I said I found this solution finally I did not say I created this solution, earlier I was missing on right-click on the table so every time a new table was created that I did not want and that was the question

Comment: did you use any generative AI in the writing of any part of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

For ***Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 19.1***

- Connect to server
- Select database (not table)
- Right click on database
- Select `Tasks` -> `Import Data...`*
- Select `Flat File Source`

*Do not select `Import Flat File...` directly. This launches new verion of Import Wizard which does not allow import into already existing table.

Comment: Please note the main point or step that I was missing on earlier was not doing the right-click on the existing table in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and choose "Import Data" from the context menu. This step is crucial because it initiates the data import process with the intention of importing data into the selected existing table, rather than creating a new one.